# Add UICollectionView to iOS 8 Custom Keyboard

Tags: ios

I want to add collection view in custom keyboard. when i hook the `collectionview's` delegate and datasource method.It gives the warning:

> plugin imesh.Mink-Chatter-KeyBoard.MinkChatter-KeyBoard interrupted
>   2015-09-04 12:02:25.627 Mink Chatter KeyBoard[1454:21160]
>   viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error
>   Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain error 3.)"
>   UserInfo=0x7f9010de0f80 {Message=Service Connection Interrupted}

Comment: did anyone solve this 